# issue with reading data from URL

Tags: java, html, url

I have a strange situation trying to read data from a web site using different values for one parameter. For some parameter values reading goes perfectly fine, but for some other values, some html elements are not read.
You can see my sample code here, and you can give it a try :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ReadLevel {
    private final static String SITE_ADDRESS = "http://www.hidmet.gov.rs/eng/hidrologija/izvestajne/prognoza.php?hm_id=" ;
    private final static String LEVEL_GIF_PATH = "../../../repository/ikonice/interf/nivo.gif";
    private final static int SLANKAMEN = 42040;
    private final static int BEZDAN = 42010;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadLevel r = new ReadLevel();
        Integer sID = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : Integer.valueOf(BEZDAN);
        Integer level = r.readLevelForStation(sID);
        System.out.println(String.format("water level at station %d is %d", sID, level));
        
        sID = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : Integer.valueOf(SLANKAMEN);
        level = r.readLevelForStation(sID);
        System.out.println(String.format("water level at station %d is %d", sID, level));
    }

    public Integer readLevelForStation(Integer stationID){
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br;
        String line;
        try {
            url = new URL(SITE_ADDRESS + stationID.toString());
            System.out.println(url);
            
            is = url.openStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            boolean alreadyFound = false;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !alreadyFound) {
                Integer levelTry = getLevelFromLine(line);
                if(levelTry != null) {
                    br.close();
                    return levelTry;
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
             mue.printStackTrace();
             return null;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
             ioe.printStackTrace();
             return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Integer getLevelFromLine(String line){
        int pathIndex = line.indexOf(LEVEL_GIF_PATH);
        if(pathIndex > -1){
            int nbspIndex= line.indexOf("nbsp;", pathIndex);
            int levelIndex = nbspIndex + 5;
            String levelAsString = "";
            System.out.println(line);
            while (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(levelIndex)))
                levelAsString += line.charAt(levelIndex++);
            try {
                int level = Integer.parseInt(levelAsString);
                return level;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("No level data for this station");
                return null;
            }
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Here is output text (sorry for formatting, could not avoid it) :

> http://www.hidmet.gov.rs/eng/hidrologija/izvestajne/prognoza.php?hm_id=42010
>
> ```
> <td class="bela75"><img src="../../../repository/ikonice/interf/nivo.gif" width="14" height="44" alt="Stanje nivoa u profilu" />&nbsp;295</td>
> ```
>
> water level at station 42010 is 295
>
> http://www.hidmet.gov.rs/eng/hidrologija/izvestajne/prognoza.php?hm_id=42040
>
> ```
> <td class="bela75"><img src="../../../repository/ikonice/interf/nivo.gif" width="14" height="44" alt="Stanje nivoa u profilu" />&nbsp;</td>
> ```
>
> No level data for this station

You can see that for param value 42010 reading works fine, but for param value = 42040 appropriate html line is without integer value at the end. But, if you load appropriate url into browser, you'll see that the value exists. You can see same thing if you take a look at html source in browser.

So, my question is - what can be happening here so my algorithm does not read whole html as browser does ? (It also happens in other lines where there are such dynamicly loaded values, not only this one.)

Comment: 42040 does not return values in browser. I suggest you filter on "Date:" too as as `hm_id=42040` => THURSDAY, 01.01.1970

Comment: Hm, you have directed me to find a workaround. Site is a bit confusing, there are a lot of similar pages, and all of them in 3 cultures - serbian cyrilic, serbian latin, and english. I've  started with serbian latin, and then turned to english in order to prepare it for this question, but I did not realise additional differencies. Now I see that - instead of http://www.hidmet.gov.rs/eng/hidrologija/izvestajne/prognoza.php?hm_id=42040, I can also use http://www.hidmet.gov.rs/eng/hidrologija/izvestajne/bezprognoza.php?hm_id=42040, and that this varioation actually works fine.
Thanks.